# ng-options appears to be adding watchers for every item in the scope

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-scope, ng-options

For some reason when I use ng-options angular is adding watchers on what appears to be every object in my scope.  For instance when I use the code below

`ng-options="item.name as item.description for item in ::controller.lists.states"`

That `<select>` field has 80 watchers (using the code from https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef#.udo2u2egs).

There are 4 other `<select>`s on the page and each of those are adding 80 watchers as well.

If I hard code the options then watchers go away, it's only when I use ng-options.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: I care because it's leading to performance issues with my app.  My target browser is I.E. 11 and I'm over 2,000 watchers.  after some investigation the majority of the watchers are coming from these `<select>`s.  On one part of the app I was able to hard code the `<option>'s`  and drastically reduce the watchers, but Ideally the values of the options will come from the server so I don't have to make code changes everytime a new options is needed.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Take http://plnkr.co/edit/EXd7QZPeOuYYrYF78pee?p=preview for example: it only has 3 watchers. Try coming up with a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: So when I go and look at that plunk using the watch counter function I referenced in my original post I am getting 398 watchers on the select element which is essentially everything on the entire page including a bunch of plunkr stuff.  

Maybe I am using the function wrong but I ran it once and saw 398 watchers, then I used chrome to inspect the select object and ran `getWatchers($0)` got 398.  I also ran it on some of the other div's on the page and was seeing around 10 watchers on those.

Comment: Open http://run.plnkr.co/Sj86jDbl61cenKq7/ (to have just the page, and not all the plunkr stuff, Then open the chrome console and copy-paste the code snippet from your medium blog post. I get 3 as result.

Comment: I tried to open the link you provided but I got `Preview has expired or project does not exist.`  I was going to try and add a couple of more objects onto the scope, my suspicion is that if you look at the list of watchers on the `<select>` you will see those new objects as well even though they have nothing to do with the select.